# Let A be a $3\times3$ real orthogonal matrix. Prove that there exists a vector $w$ in $R^{3}$ such that $Aw=w$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

Let A be a $3\times3$ real orthogonal matrix. Prove that there exists a vector w in $R^{3}$ such that $Aw=w$ or $Aw=-w$ .

**Tried:**
$(Aw)'Aw = w'A'Aw=w'w$$\implies Aw=w$
I think it is incorrect.

Comment: But isn't it that $A\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the characteristic polynomial of $A$ has the degree $3$ then by the intermediate value theorem $A$ has at least one real eigenvalue. Let $\lambda$ a real eigenvalue of $A$ and $x$ an associated eigenvector then
\begin{align*}
\lambda^2 \Vert x\Vert^2&=\langle Ax,Ax\rangle\\
&=\langle x, A^TAx\rangle\\
&=\Vert x\Vert^2
\end{align*}
This implies $\lambda^2=1\iff \lambda=\pm1$.